# Qt qspinbox editingFinished signal on value changed

Tags: qt

According to the Qt documentation:

> **void QAbstractSpinBox::editingFinished () [signal]**
>   This signal is emitted editing is finished. This happens when the spinbox loses focus and when enter is pressed.

Is it possible (preferably out-of-the-box) to have this signal fire on every change of the spinbox, not just enter or lose focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is different. You can use [valueChanged()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qspinbox.html#valueChanged) signal instead.

Comment: of course! i was looking at the signals of abstractspinbox and only saw editingFinished ... thanks for the quick reply!