# QSpinBox with editingFinished signal in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

When I use `valueChanged` signal for QSpinBox, it reacts both when I click on the arrows, and when I type any character in the text field of the QSpinBox.

I would like to have a `editingFinished`signal for QSpinBox, so it reacts only on Enter or Tab, when I change values in the spinbox textfield.

Apparently, this used to be a possibility, according to these links:

- [about QSpinBox, how to make it emit editingFinished signal when click the "up/down" arrow button ?? | Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/61529/about-qspinbox-how-to-make-it-emit-editingfinished-signal-when-click-the-up-down-arrow-button)
- [Qt qspinbox editingFinished signal on value changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290350/qt-qspinbox-editingfinished-signal-on-value-changed)

Unfortunately, when I use this code:

```py
self.spinbox.editingFinished.connect(self.on_spinbox_change_value)
```

... I get:

```
...
  File "test/test.py", line 63, in __init__
    self.spinbox.editingFinished.connect(self.on_spinbox_change_value)
TypeError: decorated slot has no signature compatible with editingFinished()
```

So, apparently, this is not a possibility anymore in PyQt5? Is there a workaround I could use instead?

---

EDIT: A minimal reproducible example:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Example(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):

    self.slider_hbox = QHBoxLayout()

    self.tspinbox = QSpinBox()
    self.tspinbox.setMinimumSize(1,1)
    self.tspinbox.setMaximum(100)

    #self.tspinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.on_tspinbox_change) # works, but reacts on every new character typed in textbox of spinbox
    self.tspinbox.editingFinished.connect(self.on_tspinbox_change) # TypeError: decorated slot has no signature compatible with editingFinished()

    self.slider_hbox.addWidget(self.tspinbox, 1)

    self.setLayout(self.slider_hbox)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 220, 170)
    self.setWindowTitle('Tester')
    self.show()

  @pyqtSlot(int)
  def on_tspinbox_change(self, value):
    print("on_tspinbox_change {}".format(value))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc - minimal example added in edit

Comment: You could explain in detail what you want

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc - in OP code, if I react on valueChanged, it would have trigggered each time a new (valid) character was typed in the spin box - so if I wanted to enter 23, it would have reacted when I enter "2" (and print value "2"), and then it would have reacted when I typed "3" afterwards (and print value "23" which is what I'd want); so I wanted `editingFinished`, so it would react only on Enter (i.e. when I'm finished typing the whole number) - I think I have it solved now, see answer posted below.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, turns out it works - I just made a mistake copy-pasting `@pyqtSlot(int)` - it should have just been `@pyqtSlot()` (and respectively, just `def on_tspinbox_change(self):`); here is the corrected code that works:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Example(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):

    self.slider_hbox = QHBoxLayout()

    self.tspinbox = QSpinBox()
    self.tspinbox.setMinimumSize(1,1)
    self.tspinbox.setMaximum(100)

    #self.tspinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.on_tspinbox_change) # works, but reacts on every new character typed in textbox of spinbox
    self.tspinbox.editingFinished.connect(self.on_tspinbox_change) # works now, if not using int argument (so @pyqtSlot(), instead of @pyqtSlot(int), etc)

    self.slider_hbox.addWidget(self.tspinbox, 1)

    self.setLayout(self.slider_hbox)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 220, 170)
    self.setWindowTitle('Tester')
    self.show()

  @pyqtSlot()
  def on_tspinbox_change(self):
    print("on_tspinbox_change {}".format( self.tspinbox.value() ))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now you will have a printout only when you press Enter, after you type in the spinbox textfield - and not on every keypress in the textfield of the spinbox ...